# How can I start MariaDB (like MySQL) on macOS, on BOOT?

Tags: macos, mariadb

I've installed MariaDB on a fresh macOS 10.11 server setup using HomeBrew. The server runs great when I start it manually, but I have been unable to get it to start automatically at boot (not login).
I used `sudo brew services start mariadb` to create a launchd script in /Library/LaunchDaemons but it doesn't work. No running mariadb, no mariadb error log. It seems to silently fail. There must be some relevant log somewhere but I don't know where.

When that didn't work, I tried making my own launchd script, first having it run `mysql.server start`, but that failed. With full path and proper permissions, but it would never work.

Then I copied some of the code from the homebrew's own launchd plist and made my own plist that runs mysqld_safe, which also doesn't work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE truncated for easier forum viewing>
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.macfixer.mariadb</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>/usr/local/opt/mariadb/bin/mysqld_safe</string>
            <string>--datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql</string>
        </array>
    <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
        <string>/usr/local/var</string>
        
    <key>Disabled</key>
        <false/>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
        
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
        <string>/logs/mariadb.out.log</string>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
        <string>/logs/mariadb.error.log</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The above leaves no trace in the mariadb error log, or the StandardErrorPath error log. However it does leave some content in the StandardOutPath log. And it looks like mariadb is starting up, it just.... isn't.

> 180326 08:37:27 mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/var/log/mysqld-error.log'.
>
> 180326 08:37:28 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/var/mysql

But again, if I run `mysql.server start` once the computer boots and logs in, MariaDB starts right up no problem at all. But when started from launchd, it seems to just silently quit immediately.

Comment: Have you tried using absolute paths to the binaries? The `PATH` environment variable is probably different between your terminal and launchd.

Comment: Yup, all my launchd plists are using full paths.

Comment: Did you check [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/231264/mysql-fails-to-load-on-boot) on StackExchange? I know it's for mysql, but it could be useful for MariaDB since they're somewhat similar. It was a permissions issue on that particular question, but it basically can be anything. Did you add the `StandardErrorPath` to your plist?

Comment: I set StandardErrorPath and StandardOutPath in my .plist, but neither results in any output. I double-checked the permissions and they are correct. I did notice that I do get one error in the system log, I'll add it to the main post above rather than add it to this comment.

Comment: Try running `brew ls -verbose mariadb` to find out where its config and error files might be hiding.

Comment: The output above tells you where the error log is. But that file is not created, despite the output from the launchd. If I start that server manually, that log pops right into existence. But if I delete it and reboot, I get that script output above, but no actual log and no actual mysql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out this very annoying problem has a very simple answer.

Make the MariaDB installation owned by _mysql:
`sudo chown -R _mysql: /usr/local/var/mysql`

And that's it! After doing that, it works perfectly.

Why doesn't the homebrew installer take care of the permissions of software it installs? Why didn't the database write to its own error log saying there was a permissions problem? Why didn't stderr or stdout from the launchd script hint that there was a permissions problem, or ANY problem at all?

... I have no idea. I'll just call it a bug and move on. But changing permissions on the mariadb install folder completely fixed the problem. And that is a huge relief.